# qdisc resets after changing to htb

Tags: network-interface, tc

**Background**

I have a system running Ubuntu which has two interfaces `eno1` and `enp4s0`. I have created an OVS bridge using:

`ovs-vsctl add br s1`

I added the two physical interfaces `eno1` and `enp4s0` to the bridge using:

`ovs-vsctl add-port s1 eno1`

`ovs-vsctl add-port s1 enp4s0`

I verified that the ports were added using:

`ovs-ofctl show s1`

To check the queueing disciplines attached to the two interfaces using:

`ip link`

The queueing discplines attached to the interfaces were:

`eno1: fq_codel`

`enp4s0: mq`

I want to change the qdisc attached to them to `htb`. So I changed them on both the interfaces using:

`tc qdisc add dev eno1 root handle 1: htb default 12`

`tc qdisc add dev enp4s0 root handle 1: htb default 12`

**The problem**

After issuing the commands for changing the qdisc of both the interfaces to `htb`, I verified whether it actually got changed using `ip link`. Initially, both of them reported `htb` as I want them to be. However, after some time, it automatically gets changed to their default qdiscs (`fq_codel` and `mq`).

I tried changing their qdiscs to `htb` multiple times, and issued `ip link` to check if they are changing. They changed to their default qdisc after a short time everytime.

**Question**

How do I permanently change the qdiscs of `eno1` and `enp4s0` to `htb`. What is causing them to reset to their default qdiscs after a short time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I will answer my question since I have fixed the issue**

This happens because probably NetworkManager (or some other process) is controlling the interface. They periodically reset the interface configuration. To solve the issue:

Check which interfaces are being `managed` by NetworkManager:

`nmcli dev status`

If the test interfaces are listed in the output of the above command as `managed`, then they are being controlled by NetworkManager. Else they will be listed as `unmanaged`.
 If they are listed as `managed`, then we have two options:

- **Option A:** Edit NetworkManager configuration file and add interfaces to exclude from being `managed` by NetworkManager:

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
     Add the following lines to the `conf` file:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:00:11:22:33:44:55;mac:66:77:88:99:00:aa
```

Replace the mac addresses, with the mac addresses of the test interfaces. On newer versions of NetworkManager, we can use interface names to do this:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:eno1,interface-name:enp4s0
```

Restart NetworkManager:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Check if the interfaces are now unmanaged:

`nmcli dev status`

- **Option B**: Stop NetworkManager.

Stop for current session (it will start again on next boot):

`systemctl stop NetworkManager`

OR disable NetworkManager (it will NOT start again by default on next boot):

`systemctl disable NetworkManager`

---

If they are not listed in NetworkManager as managed, then they might be leased by dhclient. To check that:

`sudo cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases`

If the interface is being leased by dhclient, then it will be listed in the output. If it is, either find PID of dhclient and kill it, OR edit configuration file of dhclient and exclude the test interfaces.